# Conversion of Access to FileMaker Pro

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, filemaker

I have a commercial desktop application using VBA on Word to connect with an MS Access DB running on Windows. I would like to redo it to run on a Mac as well. Since Access is not available on Mac, I must choose another solution.

I think I can convert the Access db to Filemaker Pro with some work, provide both PC and MAC customers with a runtime only version of FileMaker (by me purchasing the Advanced FM Pro.)

I use VBA within Word to retrieve, add, update records in the db. I use ADO.

Do the programatic links, e.g., VBA ADODB statements, (connection string, etc.) all work in MAC Office 2011 and Filemaker Pro 11? Again, I need a db I can connect to on a PC and MAC using VBA from Office 2010/2011. Any guidance or comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac you would use AppleScript, FileMaker has an AppleScript library.